# check if array of strings matches obj keys / properties

Tags: javascript

I want to match URL `queries` with object `keys` and `values`.

URL: `?cost=10&name=item`

```
const query = { cost: 10, name: 'item' }
const keys = ['cost', 'name']
const values = ['10', 'item']
```

How can i check if `keys[]` matches `Object.keys(query)` and `values[]` matches `Object.values(query)`? I was trying with `for..in` and different combinations of `.map(); .filter(); .indexOf() > -1` on both `keys[]` and `values[]`.

Also `10 == '10'` should return `true`.

Comment: Do you already have the raw query split into the `query` object?

Comment: @le_m yep, object has like 10 properties and url can have up to 10 queries, depends on how many filters are applied

Comment: In the example above should the test result be `true` or `false`? Is `cost` matched or not (`10 == '10'`?)?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir test should be true, and `cost` should be matched for `10 == '10'`

Comment: You might want to clarify whether a query `{a:1, b:2}` should match `keys=['a'], values=['1']` or not.

Comment: @le_m Fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the given query to be identical to given keys and values, (1) the length of both must be identical and (2) each query parameter must be contained in the given keys and values:

```js
// Compare query keys and values:
function identical(query, keys, values) {
  return Object.keys(query).length == new Set(keys).size &&
         keys.every((key, i) => query[key] == values[i]);
}

// Example:
const query = {cost: 10, name: 'item'};
const keys = ['cost', 'name'];
const values = ['10', 'item'];

console.log(identical(query, keys, values));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method on the Mozilla Developer Network. The function below fulfills the following matching criteria:

1. The number of keys in `query` is the same as the number of keys in the `keys` array.
2. The number of values in `query` is the same as the number of values in the `values` array.
3. Every key in the `keys` array is also in `query`.
4. The value at `query[key]` is equivalent to the value in the `values` array at the appropriate index.

---

```
function matches(query, keys, values) {
  const queryKeys = Object.keys(query);
  const queryValues = Object.values(query);
  return (
    queryKeys.length === keys.length && 
    queryValues.length === values.length &&
    keys.every((key, index) => queryKeys.includes(key) && query[key] == values[index])
  );
}

const query = {
  cost: 10,
  name: 'item'
};
const keys = ['cost', 'name'];
const values = ['10', 'item'];

console.log(matches(query, keys, values));
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!

Comment: `['10'].includes(10) == false` contrary to OP's latest comment, see above.

Comment: Also, returns true for e.g. `query={cost:'10', name:'10'}, keys=['cost', 'name'], values=['10', '20']`

Comment: Thank you @le_m. The updated answer fixes the problems you metioned.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the object, using `indexOf()` to see if the property name is in `keys` and the value is in the corresponding element of `values`.

```
for (var k in query) {
    var kindex = keys.indexOf(k);
    if (kindex == -1 || values[kindex] != query[k]) {
        console.log('Invalid key = ' + k + ' value = ' + query[k]);
    }
}
```

Or you could loop over `keys`:

```
keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
    if (!(key in query && query[key] == values[i])) {
        console.log('Missing key = ' + key + ' value = ' + values[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't check for when query has less parameters than given by keys & values though.

Comment: The second one checks that.

Comment: You are right! Might want to replace that `"` with `'` though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if length of object properties is the same as keys array and then use `every()` and `includes()` to check for both keys and values.

```js
const query = { cost: 10, name: 'item' }
const keys = ['cost', 'name']
const values = ['10', 'item']

var check = Object.keys(query).length == keys.length
    && Object.keys(query).every(function(key) {
      return keys.includes(key) && values.includes(String(query[key]))
    })
            
console.log(check)
```

Comment: Head-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868616/check-if-array-of-strings-matches-obj-keys-properties/42868691#comment72843573_42868616

Comment: Returns true for e.g. `query={cost:10,name:'item'}, keys=['cost','name'], values=['item','10']`

Comment: The `values` are swapped around.

Comment: Order of properties in object is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` like this:

```js
function match(query, keys, values) {
  return ! keys.some(function(key, i) { // inverse the test
    return query[key] != values[i];
  });
}

const query = { cost: 10, name: 'item' };
const keys = ['cost', 'name'];
const values = ['10', 'item'];

console.log(match(query, keys, values));
```

Or use a `for` loop like this:

```js
function match(query, keys, values) {
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    if(query[keys[i]] != values[i]) return false; // if some key doesn't match return false
    
  return true; // all keys matched return true
}

const query = { cost: 10, name: 'item' };
const keys = ['cost', 'name'];
const values = ['10', 'item'];

console.log(match(query, keys, values));
```

Comment: First one returns true for e.g. `query={cost:10,name:'item',more:'yes'}, keys=['cost','name'], values=['10','item']`

Comment: @le_m Both of them does! What is the problem?

Comment: The query has more parameters than the keys & values it is compared to. According to my understanding, this should not match. OP might want to clarify though.

Comment: @le_m He didn't explicitly say what he want so according to my understanding: he want to see if the keys match with thier values from the values array. Thus `match(query, [], [])` is always true!